# Hyperref and fullname (citations on captions)

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I am using [`fullname.sty`](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/~lcarlson/02-03/ctl292/ctl2002/fullname.sty) but it seems that, if I activate `hyperref`, it complains on all `\cite` commands that are used inside a `\caption` with this message:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.

I tried reading related threads but wasn't able to find a reason why this does not work.

Comment: \protect seems to help. Still debuging if it is enough.

Comment: I don't know about `fullname.sty`, but probably it redefines `\cite` so that it loses its robustness. Load `fixltx2e` (it's not required if you have a very recently updated TeX distribution) and do `\MakeRobust{\cite}` after loading `fullname.sty`. Where is it possible to find `fullname.sty`?

Comment: the fullname.sty name in my question is a link :-) and yes, it redefines it. Will check how MakeRobust works. thanks.

Comment: I see. Yes, it redefines `\cite`. But I'd be wary of loading a package unmaintained since 1992, probably made for LaTeX 2.09. As far as I can see, it does (badly) what you can get with `natbib`.

Comment: Indeed. I am probably changing to natbib. I can get a similar result. MakeRobust failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fullname` package is very old: its release date is March 1992, which means it was written for LaTeX 2.09.

It redefines `\cite` making it lose its robustness. It's possible to robustify it, but a trick is needed, because `\MakeRobust` is fooled by the fact that normally `\cite` *is* robust.

However, when the trick is used, LaTeX fails with “TeX capacity exceeded”.

You can work around the issue by using `\protect` when `\cite` is in a moving argument. My advice is to use a more recent and robust citation package such as `natbib` or `biblatex`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullname}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{huang2011short}

\shortcite{huang2011short}

\namecite{huang2011short}

\begin{figure}[htp]
X
\caption{\protect\cite{huang2011short}}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{fullname}
\bibliography{enet}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The .bib file is one I used for another answer.)

You could also do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullname}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

so `\protect` is not necessary any more. But, again, this is like trying to repair your great-grand-father's bike you found in the basement. Nice hobby, but just that.

Comment: And there is yet another detail. That part between the rectangular brackets should not be there :-)

Comment: @Alberto Another reason for using `natbib` or `biblatex`.